# Complexity of the Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: graphs, time-complexity, shortest-path

I'm little confused by computing a time complexity for `Dijkstra` algorithm. It is said that the complexity is in $O(|V|^2)$ - [Wikipedia - Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), which I understand. It's because for each node, we could theoretically relax edges going to each vertex so it is $n * n$ times, respectively $n(n-1)$.

On the other hand, I can't figure out why this complexity isn't $O(|E|+|V|)$. For each $v \in V$, we relax only those edges $e$, which weren't computed yet. If vertex $v$ is already computed (red on gif above), we don't need to work with it anymore.

So can I say that in one way, it is true that `Dijkstra` is in $O(|V|)$, but if we can put into the computation number of edges, I can say that it is in $O(|V|+|E|)$?

Comment: Did you miss the part where it can be optimized to `O(|E| |V|log|V|)` using a fibonacci heap?, So how do you suggest optimizing away the `log|V|` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For each v from V, we relax only those edges e, which werent computed
>   yet. If vertex v is already computed (red on gif above), we don't need
>   to work with it anymore.

Your are assuming that each edge is visited only once, but this assumption is not quite right. Let's say we have two sets $S$ and $S'$, such that $V=S \cup S'$ and $S$ is the set of vertices, for which we have found the shortest path from source $s$. Each time, we need to find an edge $e=(u,v)$ ($u \in S$ and $v \in S'$) that sits on a shortest path, but how do you find this edge? You need to either

(1) use a brute-force algorithm and spend $O(|V|)$ to look at all edges $e=(u,v)$ ($u \in S$ and $v \in S'$) for finding the minimum one, which takes $O(|V|^2)$ (because each time you are looking at the same edge that are not in the shortest path).

or

(2) use a min-heap and spend $O( \log |V| ) $ for finding that edge, and achieve $O( (|V| + |E|)\cdot \log |V| )$ overall running time.

However, if the graph is **unweighted**, your assumption is right and you can achieve the running time $O(|V|+|E|)$.